# How to customize a progress bar in Android?

Tags: android, drawing

I want to customize a Progress Bar in Android so that it looks like this: 
[image]

Note that the green background of the view where this bar chart is, is a gradient color.
I've tried to make the red bar with a drawable defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners
    android:radius="8dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

I don't defined the bar's width in the XML file in purpose, in order to be able to set it programmatically.
The bars height is 16dp.
This works find for a width bigger than 16dp, but for smaller sizes than that, the red bar looks like:

[image]

I understand why (the radius isn't appropriate for a small width), but I can't find a solution.
I would like to make a drawable that starts outside the white bar and that the white bar would clip the outside part, like this:

[image]

But I didn't find out how to do this.
Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Aaron Tuil, I can't understand your question. You want only one progress bar or bar chart?

Comment: this is progress bar not a bar chart

Answer (score 1):

Sample for your question:

***src/com.app/BarSampleActivity.java***

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class BarSampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int timePassed = 0;
    ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_sample);

        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (timePassed < 100) {
                    try {
                        bar.setProgress(timePassed++);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        background.start();
    }
}
```

***res/layout/activity_bar_sample.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/gradiant_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:progress="20"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_bg" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***res/drawable/gradiant_bg.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#21954a"
        android:endColor="#33bf65"
        android:startColor="#0e6b30"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

***res/drawable/progressbar_bg.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

***I achived like this***

[image: Output of the following code]

Try this code. I hope this is what you want (**@Aaron Tuil**).

If you feel it takes more time. Please download and try the sample source from My Repository => [Divakar-Murugesh/Custom-ProgressBar](https://github.com/Divakar-Murugesh/Custom-ProgressBar)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks @Divakar Murugesh, but I want to have the red bar with a rounded end. And also have the possibility to add another colored bar, and then, a ProgressBar won't help me, will it?

Comment: Excuse me Divakar Murugesh, actually, the ProgressBar has the possibility to set a "secondary process". Then, you were right, thank you! Then, it just missing the rounded end. I'll appreciate if someone has an idea for this.

Comment: HI Aaron Tuil, Sorry I didn't understand your need. But I updated my source in github. Please check and let me know if anything... I really happy to help you

Comment: Thanks Divakar, I've seen your code in github, but there is the same problem: when the values are small (like 1 or 2%) the bar is distorted.